# Word for someone born in the 19th century

Tags: single-word-requests

I read something about the oldest living people the other day. The article used a word that described someone born in the 19th century. I remember it distinctly because the definition stated that it included people born before December 31st 1900, and I found that interesting that it would include the first year of the new millennium (I get it, no year zero). I think it started with an “N”.

I have looked for an hour and a half now and for the life of me cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: The "Lost Generation" is sometimes defined demographically as including people born from 1883-1900.  I assume you're looking for a more technical term than that?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime haha. Yeah. Interesting phrase tho

Comment: Could the word be related to "nonadecimal"?

Comment: [*Supercentenarian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercentenarian)?

Comment: @psosuna definitely could be

Comment: @ermanen definitely not

Comment: are you referring to Centenarian? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centenarian

Comment: No. A centenarian could have been born in any certury

Comment: This article uses the term "supercentenarian" for the people born before 1900: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2014/09/05/six-people-still-alive-who-were-born-in-the-19th-century/15122367/

Comment: *Victorian* a person who lived during the Victorian (Queen Victoria) period. If we talking about an Italian, at a stretch, *Garibaldian* could be used.

Comment: Good luck with that question exactly as worded, but: nonagenarian is a person 90-99 years old but after 1999 that is not someone born in the 19th century; nonadec- is 19 as in nonadecane the chemical compound C19H40; novemdec- is 19 as in novemdecillion which is 10^60=10^(3*(19+1) (Note that bi- is 2 and billion is 10^9=10^(3*(2+1)). enneakaideca- is 19 as in enneakaidecagon, or enneadec- is 19 as in enneadecagon, either being a 19 sided polygon. None of this allowed me to find the answer to your question. Maybe some of it will help someone else.

Comment: Something makes me think that someone on 
[Latin SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com) could come up with something.

Comment: As the article you link to says, "A centenarian is a person who lives to or beyond the age of 100 years." ergo not someone born in a specfic century

Comment: Yeah, undevicesimus is 19th in Latin so perhaps undevicesimuscentarian?!

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey & .@spencer the latin approach is clever. “Undevicesimuscentarian” doesn’t ring a bell but it’s been so long at this point I don’t know that I’d recognize the word if I saw it anyway. Maybe the person that wrote the article made it up. Maybe s/he removed this made up word after I read it. Or maybe I’m just completely mistaken about what I read.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Morano  this [supercentenarian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercentenarian) who died in April 2017 was apparently the last documented person to have been born before 1st January 1900. The article does not seem to mention a specific word for 'a person born in the 19th century.' The closest word to express the meaning of extreme age would be 'supercentenarian' which is defined as over 110 years of age.

Comment: "Supercentenarian" (as described by Wikipedia, the first reference above) is defined as a person who has lived 110+ years. An "ultracentenarian" is defined as having lived "well over 100 years," presumably longer than a supercentenarian. I had previously thought this word meant "one who has lived in 3+ different centuries" (e.g. born in 1899 and survived to see 2000). Before 2010, "supercentenarian" would have worked to describe people born in the 19th century _who are still alive_, but I'd personally go for Victorian unless you're talking about a person from a region uninfluenced by Britain.

Comment: I did make my original Decemnonocentarian Comment tongue-in-cheek but still, can Spencer and I and Tchrist be the only one's who grasped the Question?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not depend in a large part on their country of Birth?

Someone born in the US in 1810 (the 19th Century) is of the Federalist Period while someone born in England in the 1880's (still the 19th Century) is Edwardian.

The only generic moniker that comes to mind is "He (pardon the pronoun) is a real 19th Century man.

Comment: Wouldn't someone born in the UK in the 1880s be called Victorian? Queen Victoria was on the throne until 1901.

Answer (score 1):

**Nonagenerian**,noun
▸someone who is between 90 and 99 years old

**Centenarian**. noun
▸someone who is 100 years old or older

**Supercentenarian**. :a person who is 110 years old or older

Assuming one of these, your source is probably 7 to 27 years old.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is looking for a word that is not reliant on the relative difference in time but the fixed century

Answer (score 0):

The Interbellum Generation is the name for persons born from 1900-1913.
The Greatest Generation (The Veterans) are persons born from 1914-1930.
The Silent Generation are persons born from 1930-1945.
Baby Boomers are persons born from 1946-1960.

Comment: Supporting evidence? You may well be right, but how can we know?

Comment: Hello, Schelling. Sadly, you're giving information about people born in the 20th Century.

Comment: Decemnonocentarian - noting the difference from decemnonocentenarian

Comment: Generation names: http://www.genconnection.com/lmu/5th/List%20of%20generations%20-%20Wikipedia,%20the%20free%20encyclopedia.pdf
'Interbellum' referring to the fact that they came of age (18+) in the period between the first and second world wars.